# Why isn't the [artificial-intelligence] tag blacklisted?

Tags: bug, feature-request, tags

I've seen several questions that use the [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) tag, sometimes as the only tag on the question. That is not useful for categorizing questions, so please don't add this to your question.

For this reason, the site name is usually blacklisted as tag name.

- So the [bug](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) is: Why isn't [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) blacklisted?
- The [feature-request](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) is: Please blacklist [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that a community manager has now blacklisted [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence). Questions that only had that tag are now [untagged](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). (The version without the hyphen, [artificialintelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificialintelligence), is blocked too.)

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange sites have a mechanism called "intrinsic tag blacklisting" that's intended to do exactly this - prevent the tag that simply describes the topic from being used.

However, the way the system works means that it doesn't always work. The system takes the URL slug *before* `.stackexchange.com`, and blacklists that as an intrinsic tag. For this site, that means that the [ai](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) tag is blacklisted, but [artificial-intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) is not. That's the explanation of the bug.

Comment: This isn't a 'bug' *per se.* We simply **try not to anticipate every problem** before they occur in actual practice. The private beta fleshes out these "problems" very quickly, so letting this stuff come up organically works way, *way* better than a community team huddling up trying to imagine all the ways this site can go wrong before it even launches. This 'bug' is largely philosophical... and by design.